# cannot add or edit content or settings

Tags: nodes, users

I am logged in as admin on my drupal site but I cannot change anything. I try to add a new article, click Save, nothing happens, the browser returns to the "add article" page with the empty wysiwyg form.

It's as if my database is read-only. I cannot edit any settings or content.

If I choose to edit an existing article, then click save, I get the page but it hasn't changed.

Also I tried to make a recommended update ("Download these updates"), when I click that button, page reload happens but nothing else changes.

Is something wrong with my database? Permissions? I get no errors on the log when doing this.

I'm very new to drupal, temporarily took over as admin for a page which had some problems.

There is another message that I should update the drupal core from 7.12 to 7.15 but it has to be done manually and I haven't looked into that yet.

Comment: Can you check the database directly? Make sure that its not some overly aggressive caching? Are you running an additional caching or performance layer (APC/Memcache/Varnish)?

Comment: Yes I have access to the database. How do I look for that? There was a problem with caching and another developer turned off caching completely as I remember it. Could that be related to this?

Comment: It may be related. The easiest way to determine if the database is being written to is to run; "SELECT MAX nid FROM {nodes};" and then add some content and re-run the query. nid *should* increment.

Comment: that query does nothing, maybe because I'm using Liya. Anyway I made a SELECT * from node which returns the same things as before. The database is not updated. When in edit mode, clicking "preview" also makes a page refresh and gives me an empty edit page for new content.

Comment: I can edit the database and change things from Liya

Comment: What version of drupal is it? Are you using any 'read only' modules? What db is it (PGSQL, MySQL, NoSQL?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4639/discussion-between-christian-and-user985366)